# Excel: Summing a column according to values in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel spreadsheet like the following:

[image: Scores by month]

I want to take the sum of a person's scores over all the months of the year in which they participated. However, not all people participated in the same number of months. In the example above, Bob was in months 1-3, while Mary was only in 2-3, and Fred was only in 3.

How can I efficiently go about obtaining the sum?

I get that if I had the months each in their own column I could do something like `=SUM(VLOOKUP(lookup value, lookup range, {months}, FALSE))`. However, reshaping data in Excel seems to be difficult in itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out just as I was about to post.

The function `SUMIF` will do it. It has the syntax SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range]), and therefore for the first name one would write `=SUMIF(A1:C7,"Bob",C1:C7)`.